How do I extract a specific number from a string / url using groovy?
I am trying to extract a specific number(without any special characters) from a url/string using groovy script.
ABC/MyABC/XYZ/POC-xyz-api-oci #89

In the above string, I want to extract only the number 89 without any special characters using groovy script. How can it be done?
I tried something like below:
    def build_numb = "ABC/MyABC/XYZ/POC-xyz-api-oci #89"

//    def cleanedString = build_numb.replaceAll(/[^0-9]/, '')
    def BUILD_ID = build_numb.findAll(/\d+/)
    echo "The build id from the string is ${BUILD_ID}"

Any help would be great.
Thanks
Pritish

What problem are you having? findAll will return a list of all the numbers. If you just want the first one, you can use find instead

Using a simple regular expression will find the first number in the string. This code
def build_numb = "ABC/MyABC/XYZ/POC-xyz-api-oci #89"

def matcher = (build_numb =~ /\d+/)
if (matcher) {
    def BUILD_ID = matcher[0]
    print "The build id from the string is ${BUILD_ID}"
}

will print:
The build id from the string is 89

